# LAST REG From a Query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the last record from this query but i don't know how to do it. I used ROW_NUMBER but my program (Protheus ADVPL) don't have resources to get the last line from a query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B1_MASTER, B1_COD) AS ID, 
 B1_COD, 
   B1_DESC, 
   B1_CATEG, 
   B1_MASTER, 
   A2_COMPRAD, 
 ISNULL((SELECT Sum(C6_QTDVEN * C6_PRCVEN) 
           FROM   SC6010 SC6, 
                  SF4010 SF4, 
                  SC5010 SC5 
           WHERE  C6_FILIAL = '01' 
                  AND C6_PRODUTO = B1_COD 
                  AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
                  AND C5_FILIAL = C6_FILIAL 
                  AND C5_NUM = C6_NUM 
                  AND C5_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20160401' AND '20160404' 
                  AND C5_TIPO = 'N' 
                  AND C5_MODAL = '2' 
                  AND SC5.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
```

(query have 106 lines so i ll not put everything)

I need the total records in a column, like this:

[Tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTv2y.png)

What can i do?

Tks

Comment: I changed ROW_NUMBER to @@ROWCOUNT and it works! Tks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX(field) too.
But, you're using ADVPL, so you could use dbSeek instead to find the last RECNO.
So, using "work area" you can find the last record with this:
`TRB->(RECCOUNT())`

Answer (score 0):

I changed ROW_NUMBER to @@ROWCOUNT and it works! Tks all